# Configuring .htaccess for subdirectories

Tags: .htaccess

Hello I don't know much about the `.htaccess` configuration, but I want to restrict access to php files on my web server and I want to have only *`index.php`* with parameters accessible.

My files are in subfolder like: *`www.mydomain.com/sub/index.php`*. I want to have access to open that *`index.php`* in subfolder, css files and js files.

Here is my configuration I have so far:

```
  Order Deny,Allow
  Deny from all
  Allow from 127.0.0.1

  <Files /index.php>
    Order Allow,Deny
    Allow from all
  </Files>
  <FilesMatch "*\.(css|js)$">
    Order Allow,Deny
    Allow from all
  </FilesMatch>
```

I have tried to do something like `<Files sub/index.php>` but everytime it restricts all php files in subfolders and *`www.mydomain.com/index.php`* works fine.

Can anyone help me with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can move all files except ones needed to be accessible by http (index.php, css, images etc.) out from DocumentRoot directory to upper level, so directory layout looks like this:

```
/lib
/files
/html
   /index.php
   /css/
   /images/
```

where /html is your DocumentRoot.

In this case you won't need any additional restrictive rules in .htaccess or VirtualHost configuration/

Answer (score -1):

htaccess may not be the best option to preventing direct access to some of your Php files. Instead, create an access value and set it to some value in the page you wish directed access to and don't set it in other pages otherwise.

```
$access = 'some value';
if(empty($access)) { header("location:index.php"); die();}
```

This way other php files will only be accessible via include or require. Hope that helps.

Comment: Why do you find this a better approach than .htaccess? It's more work, it's error-prone, and it only works for php files.